# Send verification email to any user by its id using firebase?

Tags: firebase

I am using firebase to create and manage users in my android and ios app. I have react dashboard as well. I am trying to send verification email from dashboard so admin can send the verification email to any user from list of all users. Is it possible. I mean i dont have users signed in on dashboard its just for admins and they can see list of users ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the Admin SDK you can indeed generate a verification link via the  [`generateEmailVerificationLink()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#generateEmailVerificationLink) method.

More precisely, you could call this method from a Cloud Function and when you get the link you generate an email and send it to the user's e-mail address (again through the Cloud Function).

From your dashboard, you could trigger such a Cloud Function either by calling it directly ([Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)) or by creating a record in a Firestore collection named, for example, "Admin Requests" to which the Cloud Function would "listen" ([Background Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) triggered when a document is written to the collection).